# Can't load system font by name with XeLaTeX but with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I installed a TrueType font in windows 10. Now I want to use it with XeLaTeX. The font can't be loaded. The first message is

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following rea

son: The DIN source file could not be found. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makemf.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if

you need help.

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) Couldn't find `DIN 67.cfg'
```

The first error message is

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "DIN 6776" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>. \setmainfont{DIN 6776}
```

I can use this font in Office with this name. So I tried to use the font with LuaLaTeX and it worked. I tried to load the font by filename and worked with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. This is a workaround but no solution. Other system fonts can be loaded as expected without problems. What is the problem with this font? What did I forget?

Comment: http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?sid=42fb4382072a54d0c8be39e625200e8b&p=82243#82243

Answer (score 1):

I opened the font with FontForge and generated a new TTF. Now everything works as it should. So something is wrong with some of the font names or with the file structure that LuaLaTeX can handle but XeLaTeX can't. I tried other fonts from the source (ufonts.com) and DIN 6776 was the only font with this problem.